# OnChange pass item-text and item-value Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `Vuetify` `selectlist`. When the selectlist changes I want to pass both `item-text` and `item-value` as `object` to my `onChange` function. How can I do this?

This is my current selectlist:

```
  <v-select
        :items="items"
        item-text="mediumName"
        item-value="uicCode"
        label="From city"
        solo
        autofocus
        @change="onChangeFrom($event)"
      ></v-select>
```

I now get the item-value in my onChange function but how can I also get the item-text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to say `return-object` and you dont have to pass a parameter into `onChangeFrom`

```
  <v-select
        :items="items"
        item-text="mediumName"
        item-value="uicCode"
        label="From city"
        solo
        autofocus
        @change="onChangeFrom"
        return-object
      ></v-select>
```